# Clicking a link in a dynamic table using selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[THE TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCV1d.png)

I have this table and I need to click the "Review Vacancy" link but I have no idea how to do this, it would be really helpful if someone could write some code for this so I can go over it and see what you did. The table is shown in the link at the very top. The table is dynamic so the number of rows will increase when I add new vacancies.

I located the table using:

```
IWebElement mytable = driver.FindElement(By.Id("no-btm-margin reactive"));
```

I know I have to use loops to go through the table but I'm not that good with C# I usually use ruby for testing!

The html code for the link is:

```
<a href="/vacancy/reserveforqa?vacancyReferenceNumber=1100134">Review vacancy</a>
```

Comment: plz provide html code of that link

Comment: just added it to the question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below xpath

```
       //a[contains(text(),'Review vacancy')]
```

You also try below one, which will select link which have href=/vacancy/reserveforqa?vacancyReferenceNumber i am not included 1100134 as expecting it is dynamic

```
         //a[contains(@href,'/vacancy/reserveforqa?vacancyReferenceNumber')
```

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: if i used your second example how would i make it click the last link in the table?

Comment: so if i had 12 rows how could i make it click the link on the 12th row?

Comment: use last function (//a[contains(@href,'/vacancy/reserveforqa?vacancyReferenceNumber') )[last()]   it always select last one

Comment: make a note that its select any link having that href on total page. if you required specific to table then modify xpath some thing like //table[relation to ur table]/tbody/tr/td/(//a[contains(@href,'/vacancy/reserveforqa?vacancyReferenceNumber') )[last()]

Comment: that doesnt work for me surely i would have to create the function "last" to make it select the last one it isnt an inbuilt function

Comment: cool, last function is in xpath it self. no need to create any new function. its one of the way of writing xpath. see here http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: this is how I wrote my code is this right?:                                                 

    private By VacReviewTest = By.XPath("//a[contains(@href,'/vacancy/reserveforqa?vacancyReferenceNumber')");